# How do I write a LuceneFilter to normalize text

Tags: java, lucene

So I have my basic code

```
public static final Pattern DIACRITICS_AND_FRIENDS
        = Pattern.compile("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\\p{IsLm}\\p{IsSk}]+");


private static String stripDiacritics(String str) {
    str = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    str = DIACRITICS_AND_FRIENDS.matcher(str).replaceAll("");
    return str;
}
```

but how do I put this into a TokenFilter, I used NormalizeCharMap before but that is only good for modifying a string literal, Im using Lucene 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the `incrementToken()` method, in which you will update the `CharTermAttribute`:

```java
public final class DiacriticFilter extends TokenFilter {
    private final CharTermAttribute termAtt = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

    @Override
    public final boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
        if (input.incrementToken()) {
            String result = stripDiacritics(new String(termAtt.buffer()));
            char[] newBuffer = result.toCharArray();
            termAtt.copyBuffer(newBuffer, 0, newBuffer.length)
            termAtt.setLength(newBuffer.length);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static String stripDiacritics(String str) {
        str = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        str = DIACRITICS_AND_FRIENDS.matcher(str).replaceAll("");
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually there is one bug when calling stripDiacritics need to create String to right length or can contain longer chars from previous term - i.e  String result = stripDiacritics(new String(termAtt.buffer()).substring(0,termAtt.length()));